# HTML 5.1 browser support

Tags: html, browser

So recently i read that [W3C](https://www.w3.org/blog/news/archives/5932) is recommending to use HTML 5.1 [link](https://fossbytes.com/html-5-1-is-here-replaces-html5-as-the-new-w3c-recommendation/), so i was wondering what browsers are fully supporting it already?

I did some google Search and didnt really find anything related HTML 5.1

Comment: Sorry, you are being downvoted while this question may be off topic. It is a great question.

Answer (score 2):

https://w3c.github.io/test-results/html51/implementation-report.html

This is the official report. No browser yet to fully support it as it seems.